# Allow pointer events in invisible part of a clip path

Tags: css

I need to find out way to dispatch pointer events through an element that has a clip-path property on it, in the hidden part of it. Is there anyway to do this or is this literally impossible according to the HTML spec? Additionally, is there any way to dispatch pointer events when a container is set to overflow hidden and I need to capture pointer events on the part that is hidden?

Either one of these methods would work

Here is a demo of what I need to work:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
/*  I need either overflow hidden or this clip path to register events just to the right of the green  */
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;

}

#child:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Here is the link of [code](https://codepen.io/alex-nelson/pen/xxVeeRw)

Comment: Nope, that’s not possible.

Comment: Damn, neither is possible?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: @norcaljohnny I just edited the post with a codepen